# How to set trigger to fire when variable equals another variable?

Tags: google-tag-manager

When creating a trigger we can set conditions that follow the [Variable Operator String] arrangement, however I would like to set it according to a [Variable Operator Variable] arrangement

e.g.: fire Trigger1 when Var1 equals Var2.

How should I go about achieving this? - anything in the last checkbox is considered to be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this through creating a Custom JavaScript variable.

An example of this would be:

```
function(){
  if ({{Var1}} == {{Var2}}){
    return true}
  else{
    return false}
}
```

This would evaluate whether Var1 equals Var2 and return true if they are equal, otherwise false.

Then on the specific event that leads to these values becoming the same, (e.g. click), you could set an event to fire based on the condition of this JavaScript variable's value being true.